# Entity Framework 6 erro ao logar os SQLs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando ver os SQLs executados pelo Entity Framework, uso a versão 6.

Estou seguindo esse [guia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx).

Fiz um novo DBContext usando a interface grafica. 5 tabelas apenas.

O código está dentro de um Controller Web API2:

```
public class TAGsController : ApiController
{
    private MEUDB db = new MEUDB();

    // GET: api/TAGs/5
    [Route("{Key}/api/tag/tag/{id}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(TAG))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTAG(long id)
    {
        db.Database.Log = Console.Write;
        TAG tAG = await db.TAGs.FindAsync(id);
        if (tAG == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(tAG);
    }

}
```

Ao fazer o debug eu fui até a linha do Find e ele retornou o seguinte na janela de output:

> The thread 0x8188 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Segundo o guia deveria ser apenas isso.

**Editado: Mais informações**

Ao fazer tudo igual, só que usando o `Find()`, sem o `Async()`, ele funciona.

```
TAG tAG = await db.TAGs.Find(id);
```

Existe alguma configuração extra para isso? Ou algum cuidado especial?

Comment: Cara, veja se este [link][1] te ajuda.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887864/what-is-a-thread-exit-code

Comment: Ele fala sobre o debug, mesmo sem o debug ele continua sem logar. Tem  a ver com o Async, usando o Find sem async ele funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o log não necessariamente em console. Pode ser feito em arquivo de texto, no *Event Viewer*, em `Trace`... como a ideia é passar um `delegate`, para fazer log em arquivo de texto, você pode usar:

```
context.Database.Log = mensagem => File.AppendText("C:\\meuarquivodelog.txt").WriteLine(mensagem);
```

Comment: Fiz o que vc falou com o log4net, funcionou normal, mesma ideia de passar o degate. Obrigado.